# how can i define the icon that appears on npmjs.org in my node package?

Tags: node.js, npm

Is it possible to define an icon for my node package so that it is shown in npmjs.org? I checked the package.json format and found no clue, npmjs.org doesn't give any hints either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only know about featured projects on npmjs.org, those are added and curated manually. On the project detail page, there is no icon.